# DropDown not showing selected value when loaded

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have dropdown as below:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPriority" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

From above code it should show default text as "Yes" when loaded.

I havent wrote any code behind for binding this drop down. Just wanted to have hard-Code Yes No values in it.

But its not showing me anything selected when i load the page.

Its as below when i load page:

[image]

When i done inspect element for this dropdown i got:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlPriority" id="MainContent_ddlPriority">
    <option selected="selected" value="True">Yes</option>
    <option value="False">No</option>

</select>
```

I am wondering why default selected Yes is not comming in drop down...

Note: Yes - No values are comming when i scroll the drop down, but default selected value is not comming when i load the page.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this property to your DropDownlist: `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`

Answer (score 1):

try add these properties to your DropDownlist *ddlPriority*

```
EnableViewState = "true"

AppendDataBoundItems="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this :

```
    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlPriority" runat="server" >

<asp:ListItem value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>

<asp:ListItem value="1" Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>

<asp:ListItem value="2">No</asp:ListItem>
```